# How to modify a value in a tuple in a std::list in c++?

Tags: list, c++11, tuples, std

I have a list of tuples that I am iterating over using an iterator.  I am trying to update one of the values within the tuple for each of the tuples that is not immediately deleted in the list.  The update takes while I am iterating, but it does not persist after I leave the while loop.

My code appears as follows where SpecialAttacks is a functor is defined elsewhere:

```
void implement_Special_Attacks(std::list<std::tuple<SpecialAttack*, int>> attacks){

    std::list<std::tuple<SpecialAttack*, int>>::iterator i = attacks.begin();

    while (i != attacks.end())
    {
        std::tuple<SpecialAttack*, int> tup = *i;
        SpecialAttack* attack = std::get<0>(tup);
        int timer = std::get<1>(tup);

        bool b = special_attack(timer, attack);

        if (b){
            i= attacks.erase(i++);
        }
        else
        {
            std::get<1>(tup)--;
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing by value.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How about `void implement_Special_Attacks(std::list<std::tuple<SpecialAttack*, int>>& attacks)`?

Comment: I feel so stupid now. Thanks Lingxi! That works!

Comment: Also needs `std::tuple<SpecialAttack*, int> &tup = *i;` in the inner loop, or indeed just `auto &tup = *i;` Without that, the `std::get<1>(tup)--;` does nothing.